# self signing of powershell script

Tags: powershell, digital-signature

I created a selfsigned certifiacte with Power Shell cmdlet

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName test.OJ.com -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

After that the certificate can be seen in the *certlm* under personal\certificates

Now I want to use this certificate to sign a PS script. I tried two methods
**1. with PS console**

```
$cert = @(Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My -CodeSigning)[0] 

Set-AuthenticodeSignature .\scriptTosing.ps1 $cert
```

after the first command execution the $cert variable is empty

**2. Using SingTool.exe**

```
signtool.exe  sign /debug /a ".\scriptTosing.ps1"
```

This is the result:

```
The following certificates were considered:


After EKU filter, 0 certs were left.

After expiry filter, 0 certs were left.

After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.

SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

That was tricky to find out - but in the end a very easy solution

The documentation of `Get-ChildItem -CodeSigning` says:

> -CodeSigningCert
>
> Gets only those certificates with code-signing authority. This
>   parameter gets certificates that have "Code Signing" in their
>   EnhancedKeyUsageList property value.

Your `$cert` variable is empty, because it doesn't get a return from the `get-childitem` command, because your Certificate doesn't know it's a CodeSigning Certificate, because the `EnhancedKeyUsage` Property is not equal to "CodeSigning" (also, you store the Cert in `LocalMachine`, but want to read it from `CurrentUser` which is wrong).

So when you're creating your certificate with `New-SelfSignedCertificate` you'll have to tell the certificate, that it has to be a CodeSigning Certificate.

The `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet has the following parameter:

> -Type (Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.CertificateType)
>
> Specifies the type of certificate that this cmdlet creates. The
>   acceptable values for this parameter are:
>
> -- CodeSigningCert
>   -- Custom
>   -- DocumentEncryptionCert
>   -- DocumentEncryptionCertLegacyCsp
>   -- SSLServerAuthentication (default)

So your whole Script has to look like this:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName test.OJ.com -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -type CodeSigning
$cert = @(Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My -CodeSigning)[0] 
Set-AuthenticodeSignature .\scriptTosing.ps1 $cert
```